# Chain Scrapy Spiders which have data dependencies in a twisted reactor

Tags: python, asynchronous, scrapy, twisted, yield

Actually the scrapy docs explained how to chain two spyder like this

```
from twisted.internet import reactor, defer
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

class MySpider1(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your first spider definition
    ...

class MySpider2(scrapy.Spider):
    # Your second spider definition
    ...

configure_logging()
runner = CrawlerRunner()


@defer.inlineCallbacks
def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider1)
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider2)
    reactor.stop()

crawl()
reactor.run() # the script will block here until the last crawl call is finished
```

But in my use case, the `MySpider2` need informations retrieved by `MySpider1` after transformation using some `transformFunction()`.

So i want something like this :

```
def transformFunction():
    ... transforme data retrieved by spyder1 ...
    return newdata

def crawl():
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider1)
    newdata = transformFunction()
    yield runner.crawl(MySpider2, data=newData)
    reactor.stop()
```

What i want to be scheduled :

1. `MySpider1` start, write `data` on disk then quit
2. `transformFunction()` transform `data` to `newdata`
3. `MySpider2` start using the `newData`

So how can i manage this behavior using twisted reactor and scrapy ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`runner.crawl`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#scrapy.crawler.CrawlerRunner.crawl) returns a [`Deferred`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html) so you could chain callbacks to it. Minor tweaks will have to be done to your code.

```
from twisted.internet import task
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

configure_logging()

def crawl(reactor):
    runner = CrawlerRunner()
    d = runner.crawl(MySpider1)
    d.addCallback(transformFunction)
    d.addCallback(crawl2, runner)
    return d

def transformFunction(result):
    # crawl doesn't usually return any results if successful so ignore result var here
    # ...
    return newdata

def crawl2(result, runner):
    # result == newdata from transformFunction
    # runner is passed in from crawl()
    return runner.crawl(MySpider2, data=result)

task.react(crawl)
```

The main function is `crawl()`, it gets executed by [`task.react()`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.task.html#react) which will start and stop the reactor for you. The `Deferred` is returned from `runner.crawl()` and the `transformFunction` + `crawl2` functions are chained to it so that when a function completes, the next one starts.

Comment: This isn't really different from the code in the question, though, is it?  The question already presented an implementation that uses `inlineCallbacks` to accomplish just what's being accomplished here with `addCallback`.   So what's the difference?

Comment: Yes its exactly the same :) Just noticed the second example

Comment: And yet somehow the OP thinks it is an answer. :P

Comment: Sorry, but the difference between inlineCallbacks and cie in the doc of scrappy is not clear. Twisted is another complicated framework to learn. Sorry if the questions seems easy for you, but please, don't make fun of my mistake :/